# problem with audio

Tags: sound

I have a computer with rear and front audio input, on the back I have speakers and on the front input I have headphones.

The problem is the following:
When I plug the headphones into the front the speakers stop making sound, and when I plug the headphones in I can only hear the headphones.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; why not tell us, or are you hoping we guess?   I have hardware that does this internally (ie. regardless of OS, doing it in Ubuntu and Windows equally; and this cannot be changed as its done at hardware level), where as for other hardware I can control it via software. You've not told us what hardware you're using, and most importantly what OS & release you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is working as designed.  Typically people switch between speakers and headphones.  Ubuntu by default makes headphones the highest priority output, so plugging in headphones automatically switches the default audio output target to the headphones, and unplugging the headphones switches to the next highest priority audio device.  This priority can be changed in the sound card configuration, but it's not easy and has complications.  (If you have two headphones plugged in, the most recent one will be made default.)

Sometimes after the audio device has been switched, you can use any of several linux audio options tools to change the current audio target to another device. (This will be reset every time you plug in headphones.)

However, some sound cards have a physical switch in the headphones jack, and when headphones are plugged in, not only is the OS notified of the change, but the mechanical switch may actually electrically reroute the speaker output to the headphones with no way to change it back other than unplugging the headphones.  (This allows the headphones and speakers to share a port on the sound card's electronics.)

So it is possible that you might be able to switch back to speakers or maybe even possibly tell the sound system to send the output to both devices, but it may also be possible that the port is shared and you can only use one at a time with no way to switch with both plugged in.  And without surgery on the sound system's configuration, it will automatically switch to headphones every time one is plugged in.